# doInBackground(String... urls) ends incomplete AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

onPostExecute() runs normally after doInBackground() ends..i tried putting Log.e() at the end of doInBackgound() but i see no message in log...i get skipped frames messages even tough i'm using asynctask.

```
class RssFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

ProgressDialog Dialog;
String response = "";
Activity context;
ArrayList<MyItem> mostLatestItems = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
MyListAdapter adapter;
XmlPullParser xpp;
boolean showAll;

public RssFeedTask(Activity context, boolean showAll) {
    this.context = context;
    this.showAll = showAll;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    Dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    Dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        for (String feed : urls){
            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(new URL(feed)), "UTF_8");
            mostLatestItems.addAll(getLatestArticles(feed,showAll));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return response;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    mostLatestItems = BubleSort(mostLatestItems);
    adapter = new MyListAdapter(context, mostLatestItems);
    ((HasListView) context).getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    ((HasListView) context).getListView().setOnItemClickListener(
            new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    String url = ((MyItem) adapter.getItem(position))
                            .getLink();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }

            });
    Dialog.dismiss();
}

public ArrayList<MyItem> getLatestArticles(String feedUrl,boolean showAll) {
    ArrayList<MyItem> rssList = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
    MyItem item = null;
    try {

        boolean insideItem = false;
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    insideItem = true;
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        item.setHeadLine(xpp.nextText());
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        item.setLink(xpp.nextText());
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("url")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        item.setIconSrc(xpp.nextText());
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        item.setPubDate(xpp.nextText());
                }
            }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                insideItem=false;
                rssList.add(item);
                if(!showAll)break;
            }

            eventType = xpp.next();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rssList;
}
public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
       try {
           return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           return null;
         }
    }

private ArrayList<MyItem> BubleSort(ArrayList<MyItem> a) {
    int i, j;
    MyItem t = null;
    int n = a.size();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
            if (a.get(j - 1).getPubDate().compareTo(a.get(j).getPubDate()) == 1) {
                t = a.get(j - 1);
                a.set(j - 1, a.get(j));
                a.set(j, t);
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
}
```

xml links: "http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/rss/diabetes.xml","http://www.diabetesnews.com/feed/"

Comment: you are returning responce obj from doInBackground..?what is that?
in the same method in for loop write like this
for (String feed : urls[0]){
}

Comment: Can you post the whole AsyncTask Class

Comment: can you post the example xml that you parsed

Comment: do you know ..how asyncTask works..?you return reponce(here it is null) from doInBackground which is an argument to post Execute Method(String result). Moreover you are not using that there..
just see how asyncTask works and how to use that..?

Comment: i'm completely new to android sir...what should i return ?? i have no clue... also same code was working fine before i made some changes...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set list with something which is parsed in doInBackground task.

Put this code block in onPostExecute

```
        for (String feed : urls){
            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(new URL(feed)), "UTF_8");
            mostLatestItems.addAll(getLatestArticles(feed,showAll));
        }
```